# How to remove an old celiing box that doesn't have screws?

Tags: ceiling, junction-box

[image]I need to replace this old ceiling box. I'm wondering if I have to remove it from the attic (not easily accessible). I don't know what was used to attach it to a joist (or whatever). [image]It's not a screw. Thank you.

Comment: looks like plastic ... destructive removal

Comment: Very hard to see what we're looking at.  A better picture of the entire box would help.

Comment: resized the pic. My guess now is that the box is attached to a bracket that's attached to a joist. Is that best removed from the attic?

Comment: If you can reach it without tearing up the attic floor then "yes"

Answer (score 8):

It's a bog-standard plastic box, attached to a metal bracket.
[image]

Drill out the rivets holding the box to its bracket, or just cut the thing into bits.

Comment: Great. Thank you. I'll give it a go.

Comment: If theres nothing above you can usually hit it up and break it free. If your removing the box entirely then you just need to push it up far enough to drywall over it. If your looking to replaced it then youll need to get it far enough out of the way to get a self attaching box in place.

Comment: Is that dark spot a single rivet? I would test to see ifvthat is the case. If so, drill it out and see if that frees the box.

Comment: @JimStewart - My supposition would be that the dark spot is a single rivet.  Hard to say with certainty, though.

Comment: Safely drilling a rivet (or any metal) above your head requires extreme attention to eye protection. Safety glasses alone might work, but might not. Better would be tightly fitting goggles or a face shield. It could be that safety glasses alone would work if one kept one's head off to one side and as high as possible.

Answer (score 1):

They were rivets. Had to tear apart from below. Worked fine.